# Image upload issue by ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, kcfinder

I had set up a ckeditor + kcfinder to let user upload image.

To my knowledge, the browser security mechanism would not allow server to know the client file path.

But a strange issue happened. There is an record in database shows:

```
"<img src="file:///C:/Users/ASUSUS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/xxxx.jpg">"
```

The normal code would like

```
"<img alt="" src="/mydomain/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload/images/xxxx.jpg"">
```

It caused my website failed, when other users read this data.

Could someone give me an hint about why the file path at client side would show?

Thanks.

Comment: I find the issue were caused by the user directly past an image from MS WORD.Does any one know how to disabled the function?

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the config.php file for kcfinder? Like this:

```
'uploadURL' => "http://www.yourdomain.com/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload/images",
'uploadDir' => "your_directory_path/images", // This is absolute path
'dirPerms' => 0755,
'filePerms' => 0644,
```